# To get next 5 entries(pagination) from different user ids using ajax call

Tags: php, mysql, ajax, pagination

I have a page Home.php which makes an ajax call to load_more.php. Home.php shows 5 entries but shows only 1 entry by same users(Hides the others). For the next 5 entries I call load_more.php which is supposed to return the next 5 entries but again entries with similar users hidden?

How to return the last id to the Home.php? So that when user clicks on "more", other 5 entries are retrieved and showed.

Thanks! Appreciate it!

Comment: Are you storing the complete result set in the DOM or are you making a fresh query each time?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your Ajax call is retrieving 5 at a time, you would need to pass it an offset. It would then send this offset to the database query in the limit clause. Something like:

```
SELECT * FROM users GROUP BY users LIMIT 5,5
```

This would display 5 results starting at result #6. To display the next 5 you would call load_more.php again, this time passing it an offset of 10:

```
SELECT * FROM users GROUP BY users LIMIT 10,5
```